# Xcode - Label won't clear when button is pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So I'm trying to create a simple function in my app in which a button adds 1 integer to the label when it's pressed and the other one clears it.

Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var number = 0

@IBOutlet weak var tapCount: UILabel!
@IBAction func plusTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    number = number + 1
    tapCount.text = String(number)

}
@IBAction func minusTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    var totalNumber = number - number
    tapCount.text = String(totalNumber)

}
```

However the label does clear when the minus button is tapped but when the plus button is tapped after, it adds up from the previous number before the minus button was pressed.

How do I fix this in a way so that it actually clears the label?

Comment: What is the purpose of `number - number`? And it sounds like the problem is the variable `number` is not being set to 0. Nothing to do with the label.

Comment: Yes you are doing correct just set to 0

Comment: Do you want to append number in label and clear last number when minus form uilabel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@IBAction func minusTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    number = 0  // add this line to reset the counter, the real number
    tapCount.text = String(number)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@IBAction func minusTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    number = 0
    tapCount.text = String(0)

}
```

Comment: This does not really solve the problem- he wants the text to be "number" and number to be 0.  You only did one of those things.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because when you're handling tap on minus you are altering local variable and not changing number itself. You should change "number" too. Se my comments in your's code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var number = 0

@IBOutlet weak var tapCount: UILabel!

    @IBAction func plusTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

number = number + 1
tapCount.text = String(number)

}

@IBAction func minusTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
//here totalNumber is changed but number is still the same
var totalNumber = number - number
tapCount.text = String(totalNumber)

}
```